# Is it possible to sign data in Node.js “native” (without using external call to OpenSSL)?

Tags: node.js, openssl

Is it possible to sign data in Node.js “native” from

command: `openssl cms -sign -signer ${cert} -inkey ${key} -nodetach -binary -outform DER -md SHA256 -des -in ${content}`

Comment: If this was a compiled language, I'd advise you to link with the openssl libraries and make the library calls directly. Start by looking at all the `CMS*`  functions on the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/). No clue if there's a full crypto library implemented in javascript.

Comment: here https://github.com/joyent/node-sshpk